# Powershell $args with single argument splits string

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

I try to pass a number of files to a script, that must merge files together. It works fine with `$args` and `for ($i=0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i++)` as an iterator.

I want to add a check to do nothing in case only one file is passed (because there is not need to merge anything). `if ($args.Length -lt 2)` works when there are no arguments at all, but if I try `./myScript.ps1 "Single file name.ext"`, `$args` array contains `"Single"`, `"file"` and `"name.ext"` as a separate elements. Is there a way to make powershell to always consider `$args` as an array of strings?

I also tried using `params([string[]] $files)`, but it doesn't work even in case of `./myScript.ps1 -files "11 12","13"`, giving 11 as the only element of an array.
One thing more: I need file names to be separated by spaces, as far as I'm using script together with Far Manager's `!&`, which gives selected files as a space-separated array of double-comma surrounded strings

For example, if we have the code

```
if ($args.Length -lt 2)
{
    Write-Host "Not enough arguments"
    Exit 1
}
for ($i=0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "$($args[$i])"
}
```

The results are

```
> powershell ./myScript.ps1
Not enough arguments
> powershell ./myScript.ps1 "File1" "File2" "File3"
File1
File2
File3
> powershell ./myScript.ps1 "File1"
Not enough arguments
> powershell ./myScript.ps1 "File 1"
File
1
> powershell ./myScript.ps1 "File1" "File 2" "File 3"
File1
File
2
File
3
> powershell ./myScript.ps1 'File 1' 'File 2' 'File 3'
File 1
File 2
File 3
```

Comment: Please post the code you're describing :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen updated post with code and examples

Comment: Looks like the problem here is that the execution environment (cmd?) parses and strips away the quotation marks, so the arguments received by the powershell script is no longer `.\script.ps1 "File 1" "File 2" "File 3"`, but rather `.\script File 1 File 2 File 3`. Make sure you always use single-quotes instead: `powershell ./myScript.ps1 'File 1' 'File 2' 'File 3'`

Comment: Alternatively you may backslash-escape double quotes like this: `powershell ./myScript.ps1 \"File1\" \"File 2\" \"File 3\"`